# For saltstack,how to get nodegroup of the minion in the jinjia template?

Tags: salt-stack

I want to get nodegroup of the minion in the jinjia template or pillar.How can I do it?

```
e.g. /path/jinjia_template_for_nginx.conf

{% if nodegroup == 'web' %}//nodegroup == get the minion's group
param_xxx 1;
{% else %}
param_xxx 2;
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is no way to get the node group of the current minion via a grain or a pillar directly. You can choose to export your master's configuration to you minion using `pillar_opts = True` in your master configuration, but any `salt-call pillar.get master:nodegroups:web` will get you an *unexpanded list* of hosts that is if no use here.

I suggest you create a pillar for this that maches on the group ...

```
# pillar top.sls
base:
  web:
    - match: nodegroup
    - webserver
```

Then set a value of your choice ...

```
# webserver.sls
mygroup: web
```

And then use it in the template ...

```
# nginx.conf
{% if salt['pillar.get']('mygroup', 'unknown') == 'web' %}
param_xxx 1;
{% else %}
param_xxx 2;
{% endif %}
```

I hope this helps.

Looking at the functionality of [nodegroups](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/targeting/nodegroups.html), [pillars](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/pillar.html) and [compound matchers](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/targeting/compound.html) you could consider configuring only pillar information and either skip nodegroups, or use a compound matcher using pillar data to define your nodegroups.

Comment: Pretty sure "nodegroup of the current minion" is a dangling reference to begin with. I don't think a minion has a canonical nodegroup; there's nothing preventing a minion from being included in more than one. The mapping appears to be one-way.